# Scheduling power off and on of my headless server

Tags: power-management, cron, schedule

I want to schedule power off at 23:30 and power on at 6:30 everyday.

Here are some problems:

1. If I run such command `sudo rtcwake -m off -l -t $(date +%s -d 'tomorrow 06:30')` it switches off the pc but does not switch on at 06:30 as expected.

However when I run this command `sudo rtcwake -m off -s 120` it works as expected - the pc is powered off then powered on in 120 sec automatically

2. I have scheduled such task `30 23 * * * rtcwake -m off -l -t $(date +\%s -d 'tomorrow 06:30')` (using `sudo crontab -e`) but the pc is not powered at 23:30 as expected

Can you help me with these two problems?

Thanks.

Comment: For your second command in the crontab, you need to have the full path to the command `/usr/sbin/rtcwake`.

Comment: 7 hours are 25200 seconds. Couldn't you just schedule `sudo rtcwake -m off -s 25200` at 23:30 in the crontab? (Disclaimer: I never did it, and I hope that `rtcwake -m off` takes care of shutting down the computer nicely).

Comment: When your computer is OFF, what do you think can run to turn it ON? I seem to recall seeing a "turn on time" setting in some of the BIOSes I've encountered. YMMV.

Comment: waltinator: The Real Time Clock (RTC) wakealarm mechanism will automatically wake the machine. The wake up time is programmed in the Real Time Clock and this battery backed device will trigger the processor to wakeup when the event occurs.  Thus the machine can be powered off for this to work.

Comment: Terrance: Yes, specifying full path `/usr/sbin/rtcwake` works for me, thanks
Rmano: The solution with specifying explicit time would be more convenient. I know I can create a script to calculate amount of seconds basing on exact time but for new I leave it with `-s` option as you suggested for simplicity, thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. The first problem I decided to solve by specifying amount of seconds
   for wake up time instead of explicit time.
2. The second problem can be
   solved by specifying full path to the rtcwake.

`30 23 * * * /usr/sbin/rtcwake -m off -s 25200`